# How to install java 11 in a container with openjdk11 and dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openjdk-11

I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

COPY /components/openjdk/files  /
COPY  OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_openj9_11.0.10_9_openj9-0.24.0.tar.gz /
ARG VER_OPENJDK=11

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-${VER_OPENJDK}-openjdk-amd64 \
    PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin:/$PATH"

RUN set -e; \
    echo "-- Deploy jre11"; \
    mkdir -p ${JAVA_HOME}; \
    tar zxvf OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_openj9_11.0.10_9_openj9-0.24.0.tar.gz -C ${JAVA_HOME} ;
```

and I built the image but when exectuing the container by : docker exec -it id_container bash,
and write inside the container the command **$java -version**, I got: **"bash: java: command not found".**
I think I should add some commands in the container to fix the problem and then added them to the dockerfile.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you echo your `$PATH` from inside the container? And also check content of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`?

Comment: `root@927dab518950:/# cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
`root@927dab518950:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64# ls
jdk-11.0.10+9`
`root@927dab518950:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64# cd jdk-11.0.10+9/`
`root@927dab518950:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jdk-11.0.10+9# ls`
`bin  conf  include  jmods  legal  lib  man  release`

Comment: `root@927dab518950:/# $PATH`
`bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin://usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory`
`root@927dab518950:/# printenv`
`HOSTNAME=...`
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
`PWD=/`

Comment: `PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin://usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`
`_=/usr/bin/printenv`

Comment: So you have your answer: your JAVA_HOME is wrong and should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jdk-11.0.10+9` and you should also set PATH accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following official image is based on ubuntu.

```
docker pull adoptopenjdk/openjdk11
```